# Passing Criteria on Judgement Day: What If someone meets only one requirement?

Tags: sharia, islamic-philosophy, hadith-interpretation

Let me start with this Hadith.

> It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allah said: “A man who weeps for fear of Allah will not enter Hell until the milk goes back into the udder, and dust produced (when fighting) for the sake of Allah and the smoke of Hell will never coexist.” Narrated by al-Tirmidhi and al-Nasaa’i.

There are many situations in Islam where it is mentioned that by doing a particular good deed, the paradise is guaranteed. Will it be okay to pass one criteria to enter into paradise or in every case we have to meet all other requirements as well ?

For example another HAdith says:

> Narrated AbuSa'id al-Khudri: The Prophet (peace_be_upon_him) said: If anyone cares for three daughters, disciplines them, marries them, and does good to them, he will go to Paradise.

I keep thinking, if we just meet one criteria Insha-Allah, would it be okay?

---

In the field of IT, we write conditions with `"LOGICAL AND"` and `"LOGICAL OR"`  operators. I wonder whether Allah will judge us with `LOGICAL OR` or `LOGICAL AND` in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

In the name of Allah the compassionate the merciful

### Paradise

The phrase "shall have paradise" is repeatedly reported in hadith. For example, Imam Ja’far as Sadiq (a.s.) said about Imam Hussein (a.s.):

> “If a person recites couplets about Imam Husayn (a.s.) and makes a
>   single person weep by it, then Paradise is reserved for him at that
>   very moment.”
>   We are also informed by the holy prophet (s):
>
> ومن أحب العلم وجبت له الجنة "The one who loves science shall have
>   paradise"

Another hadith from holy prophet (s) says:

« من أرضى الخصماء من نفسه ، وجبت له الجنة بغير حساب ، ويكون في الجنة رفيق إسماعيل بن إبراهيم »

In another hadith from our holy prophet (s) we see:

> Do you know what God has granted me this night?” We said: “God and His
>   Prophet know better.” He added: “He has granted me the favor of
>   choosing one of two things: the first is that half of my ummah shall
>   enter paradise and the second is the authority to intercede. So I
>   chose the second.” We said: “O Messenger of Allah! Ask God that we
>   will be worthy of it (intercession).” He said: “It will be for all
>   Muslims

But we can't say that this person will go to paradise for sure. because we are informed that our good actions will not be approved unless our prayer is approved.

> Imam As-Sadiq (peace be upon him) has said: “The first thing for which
>   a person shall be subjected to reckoning is prayers.  If they are
>   accepted, all his other deeds shall (also) be accepted. But if
>   rejected, all his other deeds shall (also) be rejected.”  Wasa’ilush
>   Shi`a, Volume 3, Page 22

So it can be concluded that, Besides being a the above mentioned hadith that show the cases the believer will enter paradise for sure, the prayers must be considered as the primary condition.